# How to improve query speed on write-heavy view with multiple joins?

Tags: postgresql

I have a medium-sized table that is write-heavy/updated frequently (at peak, every 30 seconds).

This table is joined together to create a view. Queries on this view are too slow - usually 100-500ms but can spike to 3000-7000ms.

We can't add the missing columns to the main table. We are doing some ETL, the missing columns are in many other tables, it is just a non-starter.

Materialized views was the first attempt. This was effective on query speed but updating the view was unacceptably slow. We need as little latency as possible, ideally under 1 minute, but updates were taking 5-20 minutes.

Partitioning is another idea. Updates and reads occur on a smaller section of the data. We join smaller tables into views and, whilst performance isn't ideal, it is far better. I have never used partitions though, and would appreciate an opinion on the complexity they would add.

I also looked at different hardware. Obviously, this would help to some degree but it feels like this isn't a total solution.

Any ideas would be appreciated. Obviously, there are a few things online but what I would really appreciate is an opinion from someone who has a slightly deeper knowledge than myself, and understands the trade-offs.

One big priority here, as I have said a few times, is complexity. Views are good, apart from the perf, because they wrap around what we already have. So something similar but with better perf would be great.

We are using postgres11.

Comment: It would really help to have the output of `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) SELECT...` from your view.

Comment: added explain to answer

Comment: You should capture the EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)  from when it is being slow.  What you show is not slow, it is 24 ms.

Comment: Yes, and that is why I asked the question I asked. I get that there is a desire to answer a different question or change my question so someone can answer that instead...but I just want someone to answer the question that I actually asked...that is why I asked it (and didn't include the explain or any reference to the actual query).

Comment: No one desires to answer a different question, but what you are asking is just too broad. This site exists to give answers to specific questions not conceptual ones. If you are unwilling to provide those specifics then there is little that we can do for you. If you want to provide the details then please review the help section [ask].

Comment: Right. You are essentially asking "I have a query that is sometimes slow, how can I make it faster?" We have no crystal ball, so we need you to provide the information. There is no parameter `query_speed` that you can set to `faster`.